# drupal multi site setup for a migrationed copy

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, apache2

drupal multisite setup dump folder configuration:

We migrated a drupal folder from some server to new server. And that dump was put in a fresh drupal 6 folder with old db structure and the folder         structure is as :

- drupal/sites/www.site1.com
- drupal/sites/www.site2.com
- drupal/sites/www.site3.com
- and drupal folder is in data directory.

Now I am working on www.site1.com and it has to run with a domain name called    dev.example.com. For that it is configured in etc/apache2/sites-available with Document root with data/drupal.

When I opened dev.example.com it is showing install.php page. How can I directly access settings.php/modules/themes from www.site1.php?

Answer (score 0):

rename "www.site1.com" folder to "dev.example.com".

After that go to: /sites/dev.example.com/settings.php & make sure database details mentioned there are correct.

after that you can run dev.example.com/update.php & clear drupal cache.

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: Do i have to change anything in sites-available/dev.example.com file as Document Root mentioned in that folder is data/drupal?

Comment: Make sure it is pointing to root of drupal setup, something like this:     `DocumentRoot /var/www/data/drupal` & make sure to restart the webserver if you make any change here.